# Show on last array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code:

```
for($i=1;$i<=date("j");$i++) {
  $DataGraphLinesAff .= ($i == 1 ? '['.$i.', '.$InfosMembre['imp_'.$i.''].'],
  ' : '['.$i.', '.$InfosMembre['imp_'.$i.''].'],
  ');
}
```

**which displays:**

```
    [1, 0],
    [2, 0],
    [3, 0],
    [4, 0],
    [5, 0],
    [6, 0],
    [7, 0],
    [8, 0],
    [9, 0],
    [10, 0],
    [11, 0],
    [12, 0],
    [13, 34],
```

how change code to display last array without ,

How to display `['8', 0],` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for($i=1;$i<=date("j");$i++) {
        $DataGraphLinesAff .= ($i == 1 ? '['.$i.', '.$InfosMembre['imp_'.$i.''].'],
        ' : '['.$i.', '.$InfosMembre['imp_'.$i.''].']'.(($i==date("j"))?'':',
        '));
    }
```

Comment: how to display ['8', 0],  ?

Comment: @user3027770 Could you please explain about this `['8', 0]` thing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array:

```
for($i=1;$i<=date("j");$i++) {
        $DataGraphLinesAff[] = '['.$i.', '.$InfosMembre['imp_'.$i.''].']';
}
$DataGraphLinesAff = implode(",\n", $DataGraphLinesAff);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `substr` to remove last character from string,

```
for($i=1;$i<=date("j");$i++) {
    $DataGraphLinesAff .= ($i == 1 ? '['.$i.', '.$InfosMembre['imp_'.$i.''].'],
    ' : '['.$i.', '.$InfosMembre['imp_'.$i.''].'],
    ');
}

 $DataGraphLinesAff =  substr(trim($DataGraphLinesAff), 0, -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can trim the last comma from your string:

```
rtrim($DataGraphLinesAff, ",")
```

http://php.net/rtrim